# Представление таблиц идентичных значений по условию Angular 2

Tags: html, angularjs, angular2

Есть таблица, которая итерируется по filter_product. Есть пары одинаковых значений по VIN. Мне нужно, чтобы они записывались в одну таблицу, а другая идентичная пара с VIN писалась в новую ниже. Как это сделать в шаблоне?
Как я вижу, нужно во время итерации записать старое значение VIN и с ним сравнивать новое.

```
     <table class="table table-striped table-header-rotated" *ngIf="product.vin == old_VIN"> 
     <!-- Что-то такое? -->
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <!-- First column header is not rotated -->
                <th></th>
                <!-- Following headers are rotated -->
                <th class="rotate-45" *ngFor="let product of filter_product; let i=index;"><div><span>Договор {{i+1}}</span></div></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="row-header">Договор №</td>
                <td *ngFor="let product of filter_product;">{{product.treaty_number}</td>
              </tr>
                 <tr>
                <td class="row-header">Улучшение условий</td>
                <td *ngFor="let product of filter_product;">{{product.improving_conditions}</td>
              </tr>
             <tr>
            <td class="row-header">VIN</td>
            <td *ngFor="let product of filter_product;">{{product.vin}}</td>
          </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

**UPDATE**
Должно получится следующее:

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-header-rotated"> 
         <!-- Что-то такое? -->
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <!-- First column header is not rotated -->
                    <th></th>
                    <!-- Following headers are rotated -->
                    <th><div><span>Договор 1</span></div></th>
                    <th><div><span>Договор 2</span></div></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="row-header">Договор №</td>
                    <td>2310-22</td>
                    <td>1314-82</td>
                  </tr>
                     <tr>
                    <td class="row-header">Улучшение условий</td>
                    <td>Нет</td>
                    <td>Нет</td>
                  </tr>
                 <tr>
                <td class="row-header">VIN</td>
                <td>X23254FSFS43</td>
                <td>X23254FSFS43</td>
              </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

И далее одинаковые значения по VIN должны итерироваться в новой таблице.

Comment: Покажите в вопросе HTML код, который вы хотите видеть в результате.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, добавил

Comment: Извините, но я не вижу отличий между первой и второй таблицей, кроме того, что вы убрали `ngFor`.

Comment: А не проще отсортировать данные и уже потом их рендерить?

Comment: @OlmerDale, так отсортировать можно, а как их потом отрендерить в разных таблицах по совпадающему VIN'у?

Comment: Вы говорите, что Вам нужно чтобы совпавшие ключи были в разных таблицах. В чем проблема отсортировать на два массив аи отренедерить в две разные таблицы?

Comment: @OlmerDale, а если таких совпадений тысячи, на все новый массив создавать и сортировать?

Comment: ага! А если десять триллиардов и с закрытыми глазами, да ещё в прыжке :) Вы о чем? В вопрсе говорится что нужно только отсортировать по схожим признакам и разделить на две. Какие тысячи?

Comment: @OlmerDale, в вопросе не про две. Имеется ввиду уникальные пары каждый раз рендерятся ниже в новой таблице. Таких совпадений может быть много, не тысячи конечно, но все же.

Comment: давайте так - если вы объясняете требующийся Вам функционал точно, и я понимаю Вас правильно, то посудите сами, как ещё Вы можете в шаблоне рендерить беспорядочные данные упорядочено?
Два варианта, либо отсортировать данные сразу, либо писать директиву или pipe которые будут сортировать уже дом дерево. Я бы прибег к первому варианту.

Answer (score 1):

Такие извращения конечно лучше делаются на `XSLT`. Но и на `Angular` можно.
Так по порядку, первое это нужно собрать простенький Pipe группировки, а ля:

```
@Pipe({name: 'groupBy'})
export class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Array<any>, field: string): Array<any> {
    const groupedObj = value.reduce((prev, cur)=> {
      if(!prev[cur[field]]) {
        prev[cur[field]] = [cur];
      } else {
        prev[cur[field]].push(cur);
      }
      return prev;
    }, {});
    return Object.keys(groupedObj).map(key => ({ key, value: groupedObj[key] }));
  }
}
```

Дальше сам шаблончик на Pug (бывший jade, так нагляднее, перевести в HTML не составит проблем)

```
table.table.table-striped.table-header-rotated(*ngFor="let products of filter_product | groupBy:'vin'")
    thead
        tr
            th
            th(*ngFor="let product of products.value; let i=index;") Договор {{ i + 1}}
    tbody
        tr
            td.row-header Договор №
            td(*ngFor="let product of products.value") {{ product.treaty_number }}
        tr
            td.row-header Улучшение условий
            td(*ngFor="let product of products.value") {{ product.improving_conditions }}
        tr
            td.row-header VIN
            td(*ngFor="let product of products.value") {{ product.vin }}
```

PS Как по мне верстка такой таблицы явно извращенная, если предполагается что договоров будет много то таблица должна продолжатся вниз, а не вширь ползти.

Comment: Спасибо. Но так он все равно итерируется в [одной таблице](https://ibb.co/dtRrw5). Нужно, чтобы пары с VIN'ом отдельно ниже в [новой таблице](https://ibb.co/gBvLOk) располагались.